# Program opens even with wrong login and password

Tags: python

I put AUTH.GG in my python code, it is working but when I put my login and password it opens my program right away even though the login and password are invalid, I want my program to open only if the login and password are valid

```
from AuthGG.client import Client

client = Client(api_key="*************", aid="****", application_secret="*************")

username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")

try:
    client.login(username, password)

# clear console and redirect
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


__author__: str = '                                     BG'
__version__: str = ''


S_HEIGHT, S_WIDTH = ImageGrab.grab().size
```

Comment: _I want my program to open only if the login and password are valid_, or, conversely, you want your program to close if the login and password are invalid...?

Comment: if `S_HEIGHT, S_WIDTH = ImageGrab.grab().size` is your programm code, than even if `client.login` fails it will be handeled by pring the error and then continues to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Either don't handle the exception, or re-raise it after you did what you want in `except` (e.g. print a special wrong username/password text).

If you want to keep the try/catch do the following:

```
try:
    client.login(username, password)

except Exception as e:
    print('Your special message.')
    raise
```

Or if you want to give the user the opportunitiy to correct his credentials, you could do something like this.

```
while True:
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    try:
        client.login(username, password)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print('Username or password incorrect.')

    else:
        break
```

Comment: @Isktt see edit. feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: very thanks bro, add me in discord pls isv#5460